# how to transfer body.getAsync plain text with \n

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm getting outlook email content with

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync("text", async function callback(result) {})
```

and the result it returned is in plain text format with no line breaks info, I want to know if there is any way to get it with \n ?

Comment: Are you sure line breaks exists in the message body?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the [HTML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.coerciontype?view=common-js-preview) string which represents the message body instead.

Comment: Thanks. I want it just text with \n in the right location, but now \n are autocleaned even line breaks exists in the message body.
The HTML string is the way I'm tring, try to extract the text and \n from a mess of html tags and css styles. I just want to know if there's a better way.

Comment: You can try using EWS or Graph API instead. OfficeJS doesn't provide anything other than that.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've find the solution that works coincidentally from an example while trying to use Graph API. 
See details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-preview&preserve-view=true#outlook-office-mailbox-getcallbacktokenasync-member(1)

Comment: Great! It make sense to mark the answer then.