# How to keep line breaks when getting an email body from Outlook Web Add-in

Tags: javascript, outlook, outlook-addin, line-breaks, outlook-web-addins

I am currently working on an Outlook Add-In to take the body of an email and post it to an external API. The issue I am having is that everytime I use body.getAsync(), all line breaks are removed, which causes issues with the processing the API is trying to do.
I have read many similar questions to this, but none seem to actually have a solution, other than to call getAsync with the Office.CoercionType.Html type, which I don't believe is actually a solution to this problem.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
This is my code:

```
    var body = '';
    item.body.getAsync('text', function (result) {
        body = result.value.trim();
        $.ajax({
            //some ajax call
        });
    })
```

The email bodies definitely do have line breaks within the html, as when I copy and paste the content into a plain txt file, it displays correctly.
Please note, this post ([how to transfer body.getAsync plain text with \n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72196673/how-to-transfer-body-getasync-plain-text-with-n/77059525?noredirect=1#comment135847151_77059525)) contains a similar question, but the answer is exactly what I'm trying to avoid, and I do not believe actually answers the question.
The OP mentions in the comments that they have found a way to get it working, but does not clarify what this is, therefore I wish to open this question again.